# How to prevent high memory usage for Oracle RDBMS Kernel Executable?

Tags: windows-8.1, database, memory-leaks, oracle-12c

I had set up `Oracle DB 12c` to my computer a few days ago and it slowed my computer down badly. I noticed that is causing high memory usage today. This usage stems from `Oracle RDBMS Kernel Executable` as you see in the picture. What can I do for this?

[image: Picture]

**EDIT:**

I tried to restarting the service which is called OracleServiceTEST but it didn't give a solution.

Comment: How have you identified this is a leak & not simply high but valid memory usage?

Comment: @Tetsujin We set it up to different computers. It didn't affect them as in this computer. I am not sure but it seems like leak in this computer.

Comment: It's only a memory leak if it's not actually doing something valid with the memory. As it's also creating disk usage (see the 0.1mb/s) it seems it maybe actually running a query (abet slowly)?

Comment: @djsmiley2k I didn't write any code, or query?

Comment: You still have not specifically indicated how you determined there was a memory leak.  If there was a memory leak in the version you were using, it would affect all your instances of that version, instead of just a single instance.  A memory leak is a programming error, what you describe, is simply high memory usage.

Comment: @Ramhound Well,.. I edited my question..

Comment: I assume, you have tried to restart the service, and the high memory usage returns?

Comment: @Ramhound It is exactly as you said..

Comment: Edit your question

Comment: Do you want to reduce the memory usage or fix the performance problem? What did you set the memory target values to?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I didn't set any value and yes, I want to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: @NoWeDoR Well then set a low value!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Can you explain how I can do it?

Comment: @NoWeDoR It's in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMIN/managing-memory.htm#ADMIN11201).

Answer (score 1):

back up the data in DBS folder of your oracle home. Then run the following commands when connected as sys as sysdba.

`Show parameter sga;` -
you will see the size will be around 2.5G change it to desired numbers.

Below is an example:

```
Alter system set sga_max_size=1200M scope=spfile;
alter system set sga_target = 800M scope=spfile;
Shut immediate
Startup
```

Then check for `show parameter sga` and you will see new values .

Comment: Perfect worked for me Thanks